# Surjectivity of an alternating, non degenerate bilineair form

Tags: bilinear-form, symplectic-linear-algebra

I have a function $\varphi: V \times V \to k$ where $V$ is a vector space over ground field $k$ (although I would also like to prove this for $R$-modules). I know that $\varphi$ is alternating, that is $\varphi(v,v) = 0$ for all $v$, and non degenerate, that is if $\varphi(v,w) = 0$ for all $w$ then $v$ is the zero vector. ($\varphi$ is symplectic)

Is it possible to conclude from these facts that $\varphi(v,-): V \to K $ is surjective for all $v$? Are there other assumptions that wil make $\varphi(v,-): V \to K $ surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this map is always surjective for $v\neq 0$. Find a $w$ such that $\varphi(v,w)\neq 0$, then you can obtain any element $x$ of $K$ by plugging in $(x/\varphi(v,w))w$.

Comment: Could this be extended to also work on $R$-modules, where $\varphi(v,w)^{-1}$ may not exist in $R$?

Comment: Not in general, no. For example, you could take any bilinear form where surjectivity holds and multiply the whole form by a nonunit non-zero divisor to obtain a counterexample.

Comment: Hmm, that is indeed true. I am trying to prove it where $R = \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ and your answer explains that this will work if $N$ is prime, and will not hold for general $R$. Do you see any way that will improve the result for different $N \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Krijn Not off the top of my head. If I needed surjectivity for some reason I would just include it as a hypothesis.